# BigQuery ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com

Tags: google-bigquery, google-compute-engine

I have a django server running on Compute Engine streaming data to BigQuery. I am seeing randomly this error:

```
 ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com
```

The error usually appear when the load is high.

Comment: Could you share your DNS settings on the instance (ie /etc/resolve.conf)?

Comment: @David I had the issue only in a docker environment, under high load. Outside of docker I do not have the issue anymore.

Comment: I do have the same on a Germany based server. No high load. For FusionTables

Comment: I was in a docker container and I did not have the issue without. So we decided to stop using docker. I tried to investigate deeply to understand why and I never found out.

Comment: I've run in exactly the same issue with a f1-micro instance and gci-beta-52-8350-60-0 image and the google/cloud-sdk docker container, trying to gsutil rsync (first ~15mins, downloads worked OK, then I got errors).

Comment: @as I was in a docker container. It worked well outside the container.

Comment: @poiuytrez: yes, I was using docker as well.

Comment: @poiuytrez Were you able to resolve the issue? If so, can you please post the answer so other people can benefit from it.

Comment: I don't have the answer.